What causes the problems in a linear fit when using the nlsLM function from the minpack.lm library?
The problem occurs when running
x <- data3$angle
y <- Xb_exp

triple_wiebe <- function(angle,t2, t3, B1, B2, a1, a2, a3, m1, m2, m3, dt1, dt2, dt3) {
  Xb_f <- B1 * (1 - exp(-a1 * ((angle - (-2)) / dt1)^(m1 + 1)))
  Xb_s <- B2 * ((1 + sign(angle - t2)) / 2) * (1 - exp(-a2 * ((angle - t2) / dt2)^(m2 + 1)))
  Xb_t <- (1-b1-b2) * ((1 + sign (angle- t3)) / 2) * (1- exp (-a3 * ((angle- t3) / dt3)^(m3 + 1)) )
  return(Xb_f + Xb_s + Xb_t)
}

  setting <- nlsLM(
    and ~ triple_wiebe(x, t2, t3, B1, B2, a1, a2, a3, m1, m2, m3, dt1, dt2, dt3),
    start = c(t2 = 0, t3 = 10,
              B1 = 0.45, B2 = 0.31,
              a1 = 3, a2 = 3, a3 = 3,
              m1 = 1, m2 = 1, m3 = 1,
              dt1 = 18.79, dt2 = 34.46, dt3 = 58.19),
    lower = c(t2 = 15, t3 = 30,
              B1 = 0, B2 = 0, 
              a1 = 2.3, a2 = 2.3, a3 = 2.3,
              m1 = 0, m2 = 0, m3 = 0,
              dt1 = 0, dt2 = 0, dt3 = 0),
    upper = c(t2 = 15, t3 = 30,
              B1 = 4, B2 = 5,
              a1 = 6.9, a2 = 6.9, a3 = 6.9,
              m1 = 10, m2 = 10, m3 = 10,
              dt1 = 40, dt2 = 60, dt3 = 80),
    control = nls.lm.control(ftol = 1e-8, ptol = 1e-8, maxfev = 5000)
  )
summary(setting)

The mistake is :

Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Prior to the code provided, it was tested with a simpler function which worked accurately but the adjustment does not have a good approximation, so it was tested with a triple wiebe function.

Simple functional function: 

x <- data3$angle
y <- Xb_exp

triple_wiebe <- function(x, a, m) {
  return(1 - exp(-a * ((x - (-2.3)) / 81)^(m + 1))) ##
} 
fit <- nlsLM(y ~ triple_wiebe(x, a, m), 
                start = c(a = 3, m = 1),
                lower = c(a = 2.3, m = 1),
                upper = c(a = 6.9, m = 10),
                control = nls.lm.control(ftol = 1e-8, ptol = 1e-8, maxfev = 5000))
summary(setting)

a_optimal<-6.313 
m_optimal<-1,000

Xb_opt <- (1 - exp(-a_optimal * ((x - (-2.3)) / 81)^(m_optimal + 1))) 
data3<-cbind(data3, Xb_opt)

ggplot(data3, aes(x = angle)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Xb_exp, color = "Xb"), shape = 1, size = 3.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Xb_opt, color = "Xb_opt"), size = 1) +
  labs(title = "Plot of Xb and Xb_opt as a function of theta",
       x = "theta",
       y = "Xb / Xb_opt") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Lines", values ​​= c(Xb_exp = "skyblue2", Xb_opt = "red"), labels = c("Xb", "Xb_optimo")) +
  theme_minimal() 

Result:
Result Simple functional function 
Triple wiebe function that you want to apply for a better adjustment:
Triple wiebe
Vectors:
data3$angle:[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
Xb_exp:[0.0000000000, -0.0009960605, 0.0016532760, 0.0102702370, 0.0269182418, 0.0504423914, 0.0812982160, 0.1247604905, 0.1757399258, 0.2316026482, 0.2865171425, 0.3382559771, 0.3877024819, 0.4350117886, 0.4824038097, 0.5276377309, 0.5713860008, 0.6130667853, 0.6524571939, 0.6908600821, 0.7271297094, 0.7580422134, 0.7839380296, 0.8076644449, 0.8288905896, 0.8482377020, 0.8657820824, 0.8803679372, 0.8937612032, 0.9061462980, 0.9163206852, 0.9250569605, 0.9325664877, 0.9394844410, 0.9459177037, 0.9512379848, 0.9555877018, 0.9599414633, 0.9636446986, 0.9663809680, 0.9690933401, 0.9714804380, 0.9734112088, 0.9759082925, 0.9784896625, 0.9802393879, 0.9819224019, 0.9836471984,
0.9847029546, 0.9856281013, 0.9866373446, 0.9873474879, 0.9881178181, 0.9887323915, 0.9890912005, 0.9897277761, 0.9903967440, 0.9909366162, 0.9914700305, 0.9918524777, 0.9923179089, 0.9928878653, 0.9934625088, 0.9940823459, 0.9944689242, 0.9949746924, 0.9955879142, 0.9961004750,
0.9967386105, 0.9972734441, 0.9978376714, 0.9983301668, 0.9983977654, 0.9982449831, 0.9982163979, 0.9982979655, 0.9982497488, 0.9982454934, 0.9983857335, 0.9986699241, 0.9991875574, 0.9996259774, 1.0000000000]
